# Classic ASP / asppdf component and page numbering

Tags: pdf, asp-classic

does anyone have experience with dynamic page numbering via the asppdf component in Classic ASP, thanks can't seem to find it in the object refference or manuals

Comment: Please just state what you're wondering about.

Comment: ;-) right let me explain, i create a pdf file from a database recordset, say 2500 records, and dump these in a pdf file, now what i'm trying to reach is to have on each pages their own page number, so say for example: page 1 of 40, however can't seem to find this within the object refference of the asppdf component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the hassle, this was a quite an easy solution, all I had to do was a normal count loop and draw a canvas with this value within the pdf....sometimes things look harder then actually are....

below you will find my solution:

```
Set Pdf = Server.CreateObject("Persits.PDF")
    Set Doc = Pdf.CreateDocument
    Doc.ImportFromUrl "http://www.mydomain.com/assets/incs/path/script.asp"

    For Each Page in Doc.Pages
        str = "Page " & Page.Index & " of " & Doc.Pages.Count
        Page.Canvas.DrawText str, "x=10, y=20", Doc.Fonts("Courier")
    Next

    Doc.Save "c:\mypath\filename.pdf", False 
Set Pdf = Nothing
```